# Proto Buffers: include auto-generated files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I designed an interface based on Googles Proto Buffers. I have other projects (C++) which use this interface. To that end, I include auto-generated (by the proto buffers compiler) headers and source files. Is this good practice?

The problem I'm facing is that, each time I change a name of a file in the proto interface, the includes in the other projects are invalid. Would it be a good idea to build an additional layer in the proto interface with "fake includes" (i.e.: header files which include the auto-generated files, and those header files would then be included into the other projects), or some other idea? That way, I would only have to change that additional layer in the proto interface itself, and the other projects would remain untouched.

Basically, I'm not sure how to design this in order to have some backward compatibility in the interface.

Comment: Separation of domain objects from data transfer objects is indeed a good idea.

Comment: How common is it to change the file names of the proto files? This doesn't seem like a problem specific to protobuf generated files - you would have the same problem moving regular c++ header files, for example. Having a header to re-export the symbols solves the immediate problem, but it's still just another indirection - what if you want to move these "fake includes"?

Comment: @RafaelLerm I would expect to have to move those headers at least less frequently... I would have much less headers than protofiles. But I get your point of course. I'm looking for an optimal solution, if any.